# Can't choose .NET5 as prerequisite for a clickOnce application after upgrade

Tags: .net-core, clickonce, visual-studio-2022

I've upgraded a project from .netcore3 to .net5 for a application we deploy with clickOnce and want to add .Net5 runtime as a prerequisite. It's not listed as an option in the scrollview, there are only runtimes for .NetCore3 and different framework versions listed.
Using visual Studio 2022.

**Upgraded project:**

[image]

**New project:**

[image]

I could pack it in the application folder but I would rather link it and this list should update when upgrading.

I've tried restarting Visual Studio, cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

Is there a way to force this list to update itself?

Edit:

**Relevant parts of .csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.48.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <FileVersion>1.0.48.0</FileVersion>
    <PackageIcon>PackageIcon.png</PackageIcon>
    <ApplicationIcon>ApplicationIcon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please post your `.csproj` file.

Comment: What happens if you create a new .NET 5 ClickOnce project, then just copy+paste the relevant files into your upgraded project?

Comment: This turned out to be a weird one. It's the deployment mode option: self-contained vs Framework dependent. Which determines the choices. Only thing is that it comes later in the wizard.